# Python: How to I unbind a variable from instance in a class?

Tags: python, variables, instance, bind, unbind

In class, let's say I have an instance

```
self.my_instance=6
```

Then, in a method, say I have something like

```
my_variable=self.my_instance
```

Every time I change `my_variable` to some other value, `self.my_instance` changes its value also, and this is not what I want. I want to modify `my_variable` without affecting `self.my_instance`. This can be quite frustrating and confusing in large programs too.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of that behavior?  Unless you are modifying the actual object such as `my_variable.append(4)` if `my_variable` is a list, `self.myinstance` shouldn't be changed.

Comment: Yes! my_variable IS a list, and I am trying to append self.my_instance, which is a list also. Do you know how to go about it?

Comment: Yes.  Say `my_variable = self.myinstance[:]` instead of `my_variable = self.myinstance`  That will create a copy of the list.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I want! Thank you! I would like to vote your answer, but how do I do that? Sorry, I am quite new here :)

Comment: It isn't really an answer yet, but I'll post it as an answer.  Once it is posted, you can click the grey check mark below the vote count.

Comment: sure! Have a good day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say `my_variable = self.myinstance`, `my_variable` is now just an alias to the object that `self.myinstance` refers to.  To make it a separate object, you can use slicing:

```
my_variable = self.myinstance[:]
```

Using `self.myinstance[:]` means to take all objects from the beginning to the end which means everything.  Since it is a slice, however, it returns a copy so this is a common way to get a copy of a list.

This works in your case because `my_variable` is a list, but if it is a dictionary, for instance, you can use the `copy` module:

```
import copy

my_variable = copy.copy(self.myinstance) # Shallow copy
```

or

```
my_variable = copy.deepcopy(self.myinstance) # Deep copy
```

Dictionaries also have the `.copy()` method for shallow copies.

Comment: And if `self.myinstance` is some other mutable type that can't be sliced like that, you can use [the `copy` module's](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) `copy` or `deepcopy` functions, as appropriate.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: Thanks for pointing that out.  I have added that.